# How to make my python windows executable smaller

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am using pyinstaller to build my executables. Often I use a small part of a module.

Example:

```
from matplotlib import matplotlib.pyplot
```

However the compiler takes the whole module as it is and compiles it, making the size of the application rather big and clunky. How can I make the python executable smaller by specifying that I only want a certain part of a module/library (It should be noted that I am already deleting unused dlls). Either on python 3 or python2.

Comment: Without having any knowledge of how the `pyinstaller` module looks, i would suggest looking into it to see how it handles the imports and modify that part of the code